# How to include JavaScript in <script> tag instead in element tag

Tags: javascript

I know how to put javascript in an element directly, like:

```
<div onclick="this.style.opacity='0'">Some Text</div>
```

Or

```
<div onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0'">Some Text</div>
```

etc.

But Instead of using javascript in the element tag how can we provide the same action by putting the js code in `<script>` tag.

Comment: This is a trivial question which would be answered instantly with a quick search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery, you could do

```
<div class="shouldchangeonclick">Some Text </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.shouldchangeonclick').on('click', function () {
    this.style.opacity = '0';
    // or $(this).css('opacity', '0');
  });
});
</script>
```

Of course you could also do it without jquery, but don't forget that the code should be called after the dom is ready (document onload event)

```
document.getElementById('theid').addEventListener('click', function (el) {
  this.style.opacity = '0';
});
```

Comment: Thanks It helped me a lot, you are really awesome, I found this ans the best answer. THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById("id")
```

Or you could include jQuery on your page, and thing would get **lot** simpler.

```
$('#id').mouseenter(function(){
$('#id').css("opacity","0.1");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rmAS7/1/)

Comment: But what about the 'onmouseover' or 'onclick' property? How to specify the mouse action in the <script> tag

Comment: Easiest way to do it is with jQuery.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I wanna give you vote up but I can't as I am a newbie

Comment: event listener shortcuts in jQuery don't use the "on" prefix. working code would be `$('#id').mouseover`

Comment: @Roman, started thinking about the plain javascript version, and typed it wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While I'm an advocate of the `learn javascript before jQuery`, I'll tell you that the use of libraries often help you to keep your [javascript unobstrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is one of the most used javascript libraries.

Combining your two examples would lead to this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('anyCssSelector').bind('click mouseover', function() {
        $(this).css('opacity', 0);
    });
});
```

Actually, if you are concerned about unobtrusive javascript, you shouldn't style your elements in javascript. Instead, apply classes to your elements that "describe" them.
As an example, instead of "hardcoding" the behaviour of hiding your elements "on click" by setting the opacity to 0, a cleaner way would be to add a class that describes it as, for example, "inactive". Then in a stylesheet, declare that "inactive" elements are hidden by opacity. That would work out to:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/NrCqm/**](http://jsfiddle.net/NrCqm/)

```
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid #444;
    margin: 5px;
}

.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #66FF66;
}

.inactive {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>​

<div class="clickable">Foo bar</div>
<div class="clickable">Ponyo</div>
<div class="clickable">Hello</div>
<div>You can't touch this</div>
<div class="clickable">World</div>
<div class="clickable">Lorem Ipsum</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.clickable').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('inactive');
    });
});​
</script>
```

This way, if tomorrow you decide that "inactive" elements should be just grayed out and in italic font, instead of being hidden, all you have to do is change your stylesheet and you don't have to fiddle with your code. (Of course this means also you can give your stylesheet to a designer that doesn't want to see any code).

see here the changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/NrCqm/1/